# Flutter apk not install on device

Tags: flutter

I have a problem of this type if I install an apk from Android Studio on an Android device it works, but if I take the generated apk (i.e. the same one) and install it manually on the device does it tell me app not installed during installation? why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the target and minimum SDK. if the phone running on lets say android 14 and the maximum is 32 or 31 it wont work and it will show that error.  What you can do is increase the maximum and the target to whatever android version you wanna support. I had this issue before and that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Install it using

```
build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk
```

Comment: this version in not sign for send on app store

Answer (score 0):

Try to unistall the app in the device before install the apk manually

Comment: i have try but it doesn't work